# App Not Installed Package Appears To Be Invalid - Quasar App for Android build with capacitor

Tags: android, apk, capacitor, quasar-framework

I'm currently working on an cross-platform app. I'm using Quasar & Vue and Capacitor. My app is working well on desktop and is building 'fine'. But when I want to install it in my phone (or android emulator) it says 'App Not Installed Package Appears To Be Invalid'.

Here is the build log :

```
PS C:\Users\me\Documents\u\voyo-spa> quasar build -m capacitor -T android

 .d88888b.
d88P" "Y88b
888     888
888     888 888  888  8888b.  .d8888b   8888b.  888d888
888     888 888  888     "88b 88K          "88b 888P"
888 Y8b 888 888  888 .d888888 "Y8888b. .d888888 888
Y88b.Y8b88P Y88b 888 888  888      X88 888  888 888
 "Y888888"   "Y88888 "Y888888  88888P' "Y888888 888
       Y8b


 Build mode............. capacitor
 Pkg quasar............. v2.14.3
 Pkg @quasar/app-vite... v1.7.3
 Pkg vite............... v2.9.17
 Debugging.............. no
 Publishing............. no
 Packaging mode......... gradle

 App •  WAIT  • Compiling of Capacitor UI with Vite in progress...
 App •  DONE  • Capacitor UI compiled with success • 6446ms

 UI files build summary:
 ╔══════════════════════════════════════╤═══════════╗
 ║                                Asset │      Size ║
 ╟──────────────────────────────────────┼───────────╢
 ║               assets/api.a6511b54.js │   0.57 KB ║
 ║             assets/axios.15eb79b5.js │   0.24 KB ║
 ║             assets/axios.6b484fa5.js │  29.25 KB ║
 ║      assets/ContactsPage.a77d4f30.js │   0.38 KB ║
 ║       assets/CreateVisit.0ae386a3.js │   2.65 KB ║
 ║     assets/ErrorNotFound.92c9e1e2.js │   0.53 KB ║
 ║ assets/ForgottenPassword.0522cb9f.js │   2.13 KB ║
 ║          assets/HomePage.da1f2c94.js │   3.77 KB ║
 ║              assets/i18n.a47aece6.js │  47.56 KB ║
 ║             assets/index.2f452545.js │ 115.02 KB ║
 ║         assets/LoginPage.eb20bc0a.js │   5.09 KB ║
 ║        assets/ProfilPage.cd1cf1eb.js │   2.49 KB ║
 ║              assets/QBtn.e998e959.js │  16.27 KB ║
 ║             assets/QCard.c0beb4e5.js │   1.14 KB ║
 ║            assets/QInput.4a7d5195.js │  25.33 KB ║
 ║      assets/RegisterPage.35cc7392.js │   1.93 KB ║
 ║             assets/rules.6f86d38b.js │   2.75 KB ║
 ║  assets/ToolBarComponent.88d69250.js │  25.39 KB ║
 ║               assets/web.f4c3ae26.js │   0.66 KB ║
 ╟──────────────────────────────────────┼───────────╢
 ║            assets/index.c9c1fd31.css │ 197.21 KB ║
 ║        assets/LoginPage.8b133043.css │   0.08 KB ║
 ╟──────────────────────────────────────┼───────────╢
 ║                           index.html │   0.59 KB ║
 ╚══════════════════════════════════════╧═══════════╝

 App • Updated src-capacitor/package.json
 App • Updated capacitor.config.json
 App • Running "C:\Users\me\Documents\u\voyo-spa\src-capacitor\node_modules\@capacitor\cli\bin\capacitor sync android" in C:\Users\me\Documents\u\voyo-spa\src-capacitor

√ Copying web assets from www to android\app\src\main\assets\public in 351.45ms
√ Creating capacitor.config.json in android\app\src\main\assets in 10.62ms
√ copy android in 401.83ms
√ Updating Android plugins in 2.22ms
[info] Found 1 Capacitor plugin for android:
       @capacitor/app@5.0.7
√ update android in 682.92ms
[info] Sync finished in 1.101s

 App • Updated capacitor.config.json
 App • Building Android app...
 App • [sync] Running "./gradlew.bat assembleRelease" in C:\Users\me\Documents\u\voyo-spa\src-capacitor\android


> Configure project :app
WARNING: Using flatDir should be avoided because it doesn't support any meta-data formats.

> Configure project :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins
WARNING: Using flatDir should be avoided because it doesn't support any meta-data formats.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 9s
133 actionable tasks: 30 executed, 103 up-to-date
 Build succeeded

 Build mode............. capacitor
 Pkg quasar............. v2.14.3  
 Pkg @quasar/app-vite... v1.7.3   
 Pkg vite............... v2.9.17
 Debugging.............. no
 Publishing............. no
 Packaging mode......... gradle
 Browser target......... es2019|edge88|firefox78|chrome87|safari13.1
 =======================
 Output folder.......... C:\Users\me\Documents\u\voyo-spa\dist\capacitor

 Tip: "src-capacitor" is a Capacitor project folder, so everything you know
      about Capacitor applies to it. Quasar CLI generates the UI content
      for "src-capacitor/www" folder and then either opens the IDE or calls
      the platform's build commands to generate the final packaged file.

 Tip: Feel free to use Capacitor CLI ("yarn capacitor <params>" or
      "npx capacitor <params>") or change any files in "src-capacitor", except
      for the "www" folder which must be built by Quasar CLI.
```

I've already try to delete the app and rebuild it, change install device and android version 11 & MIUI14 (Android 13).
Does anyone know where it might come from or any idea to install it ?

Edit : I've also try to uninstall and install my java/capacitor/gradle and redo a project from start. Still the same error.

Comment: Is the error message "App Not Installed Package Appears To Be Invalid" what you get if you try to install the APK file via `adb install`?

Comment: No it appear when I install it form file. I can't install it using adb install. The installation message appear but do not do anythings~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to solve this. I've sign the app and now I can install it without any issue.
No Idea why I was able to install it before~